# How to rent your own space in a datacenter (not cloud provider)?

Tags: web, cloud, web-hosting, iaas

Is it even possible as a private person to rent a webspace?
For example at interxion.
How much would it cost? What do you get, do you get the hardware assigned and tell them what software you want to run on it or what?
Do you know material how to read up on this?
Is there open source software for virtualizing the hardware?
Which datacenter are applicable for private persons?

Answer (score 1):

A private individual can :
Rent webspace on a server, this is called a shared hosting account. You usually get to choose between windows or linux and generally get a control panel to install the most common packages like joomla, wordpress etc

You can also rent a vps, a virtual private server which is like having your own server. You personally remote desktop to the server and install and configure whatever software you need, eg apache web server or Windows IIS.

You can even rent your own  server or even buy your own server and have it co-located at a data centre.

The choice as to which to choose is down to how much power and control you need for whatever you're doing. I've listed the choices above in order of power and configurability. The least powerful and configurable option is at the top. The order is also cheapest to most expensive.

Key phrases to google to find out more are
Shared hosting 
VPS hosting
Server co-location

As far as who is a good provider, that's just a matter of googling around and finding reviews.